# $G\subseteq A$ is open $\rightarrow$ There is $U\subset M$ open s.t $G=A\cap U$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

> Let $M$ be a metric space, $A\subseteq M$ so $G\subseteq A$ is open in $A$ $\rightarrow$ There is $U\subset M$ open s.t $G=A\cap U$

I have saw the following proof:

Let assume $G\subseteq A$ open in $A$, Therefore for all $p\in G$ there is $r_{p}>0$ such that $B^{A}(p,r_{p})\subseteq G$ so $\cup_{p\in G}B^{A}(p,r_{p})=G$ let $U=B^{M}(p,r_{p})$ it is open as a union of open sets.

$A\cap U=A\cap(\cup_{p\in G}B^{M}(p,r_{p}))=\cup_{p\in G}A\cap B^{M}(p,r_{p})=\cup_{p\in G}B^{A}(p,r_{p})=G$

Why does $A\cap(\cup_{p\in G}B^{M}(p,r_{p}))=\cup_{p\in G}A\cap B^{M}(p,r_{p})$?

Comment: Distributive law?

Comment: Use $B^A(x,r) =  A \cap B^M(x,r)$.

Comment: Let $C(p)=A\cap B(p)$ for each $p\in G.$  For any  $x$ we have $x\in A\cap (\cup_{p\in G}B(p))\iff$ $\iff (x\in A\land \exists p\in G\;(x\in B(p)))$ $\iff \exists p\in G\;(x\in A\cap B(p))$ $\iff \exists p\in G\;(x\in C(g)) $  $\iff x\in \cup_{p\in G}C(g)$ $ \iff x\in \cup_{p\in G}C(p)=$ $\cup_{p\in G}(A\cap B(p)).$.... Draw a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't *really* a question on metric spaces, so much as it is a question on set theory and operations on sets. Here's a quick proof sketch of a slightly more general result.

Let $x\in A\cap (\bigcup_{\beta \in B}X_\beta)$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\in X_\gamma$ for some $\gamma\in B$. Thus, $x\in A\cap X_\gamma$, and so $x\in \bigcup_{\beta\in B}A\cap X_\beta$. Suppose conversely that $x\in \bigcup_{\beta\in B} A\cap X_\beta$. Then $x\in A$ and $X_\delta$ for some $\delta\in B$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\in \bigcup_{\beta\in B}X_\beta$. So, $x\in A\cap (\bigcup_{\beta\in B}X_\beta)$.

Thus, $A\cap (\bigcup_{\beta\in B}X_\beta)=\bigcup_{\beta\in B}A\cap X_\beta$.